# Groovy Closures and Params

Tags: grails, groovy

In groovy you got closure which I kinda get, (similar to js, and ruby blocks) but I came across this code and I would like some clarification.

```
def bar = {
 -1
}

..
..
.

getResults foo, bar , params, Foo.class.simpleName
```

Which get getResults is a method that takes a closure bar as a parameter. What I don't get is that in the method it has this:

```
public int getResults ( foo, bar , params, classSimpleName) {
    def totalCount = bar(params)
..
..
.
```

Now bar(params) returns -1 which is the value of it. But I dont get how it works.
is params a predefined word?

I am working in Grails and I know that my params passed to to controller, have no bar variable in them, and I dont know how they are related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bar` is a closure. You are invoking the closure with `params` parameter. `bar` closure does not care about any parameters. It always returns `-1`. That's it.

`params` is a predefined variable in grails controllers.